# Some CSS Class selectors don't work in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm working on some basic styling for my personal project, and for some reason, most of the class selectors in my css file Header.css works, except `headerOptionCount`. Earlier, some other classes weren't working, but putting Header.css in a styles directory seemed to help, but now it is happening again. When changing `margin-left` and `margin-right` of `headerOptionCount`, nothing changes. When inspecting the element in dev tools, the styles dont show up at all.

Header.css:

```
.header {
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #131921;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}

.headerLogo {
    width: 60px;
    object-fit: contain;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.headerSearch {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 24px;
}

.headerSearchInput {
    width: 100%;
    height: 12px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: none;
}

.headerSearchIcon {
    padding: 5px;
    height: 22px !important;
    background-color: tomato;
}

.headerOptionLineOne {
    font-size: 10px;
}

.headerOptionLineTwo {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 800;
}

.headerOptionBasket {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
}

.headerOptionCount {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.headerNav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.headerOption {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: white;
}
```

Here is my Header component that imports this css file.
Header.js:

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "../zipshopIcon.png";
import { Search, ShoppingCart } from "@material-ui/icons";
import "../styles/Header.css";

const Header = () => {
    return (
        <div className="header">
            <img className="headerLogo" src={logo} alt="Logo" />

            <div className="headerSearch">
                <input className="headerSearchInput" type="text" />
                {/* Logo */}
                <Search className="headerSearchIcon" />
            </div>

            <div className="headerNav">
                <div className="headerOption">
                    <span className="headerOptionLineOne">Hello Guest</span>
                    <span className="headerOptionLineTwo">Sign In</span>
                </div>

                <div className="headerOption">
                    <span className="headerOptionLineOne">Returns</span>
                    <span className="headerOptionLineTwo">& Orders</span>
                </div>

                <div className="headerOption">
                    <span className="headerOptionLineOne">Your</span>
                    <span className="headerOptionLineTwo">Prime</span>
                </div>
                <div className="headerOptionBasket">
                    <ShoppingCart />
                    <span className="headerOptionTwo headerBasketCount">0</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

The import directory is definitely correct since the other styles work. I've tried using css modules, but it didnt fix anything. Should i try using scss? it just baffles me why class selectors cant even work when imported as css files. Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I couldn't see anywhere in ```header.js``` you have included the class ```headerOptionCount``` .. I think you have given ```headerBasketCount``` instead of  ```headerOptionCount``` ..

Comment: okay im actually dumb haha thanks for the catch

Comment: No issues.. Happy coding..

Answer (score 0):

None of your elements in the js have the classname `headerOptionCount`, you need to give the element you want to have those styles the classname for it to work.